# How do delete this file?

Tags: macos

I have:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/git
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  18176  3 gru 07:36 /usr/bin/git
```

Now:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/git
```

Gives:

```
rm: /usr/bin/git: Operation not permitted
```

So, I really do not know what to do.

Comment: I think you need to enable the root user, then `su root`, then you should be able to `rm` the file.

Comment: This is one of the oddities on an Apple system.  As I understand it Apple's sudo is not really a full root user.   That is something I have come across in the past.  This post suggests something about flags - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193831/unable-to-delete-locked-file  It could be also that the file is locked by another process, say xcode?

Comment: http://www.cnet.com/news/mini-tutorial-force-deleting-stubborn-or-problematic-files-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: It probably has an equivalent of Linux’ immutable flag set. But what are you trying to achieve anyway? It doesn’t sound like you’re going the right way.

Answer (score 1):

In the most recent release of OSX, *El Capitan*, Apple has added protection to the files in `/usr/bin` (and other directories).  They call it [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899):

> In OS X, the “root” user account previously had no permission restrictions and could access any system folder or application on your Mac. Software gained root-level access when you entered your administrator name and password to install it and could then modify or overwrite any system file or application.
>
> System Integrity Protection restricts the root account and limits the actions that the root user can perform on protected parts of OS X.

If you have sufficient permissions, you *can* override this (see comments in *[How to Disable System Integrity Protection (rootless) in OS X El Capitan](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/)* posted in OsxDaily).

Given the pros/cons, doing this is something not advisable for most people.

Rather, you should look into *adding* a version of git which you can manipulate (and remove if needed), such as from [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=git) or [homebrew](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Getting-Started-Installing-Git).